# how to automatically delete rows when all checkboxes are checked in microsoft access database?

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, checkboxlist

I'm on my way on creating a simple Database for a company. This database contains several tables, one of the tables will record information about the training that had been completed by each employee. There are about ten sections of training that should be completed.

I plan to put these sections into checkboxes to make it easier for the admins to see which sections the employee has been finished, and which sections the employee hasn't finished yet.

I have already made the table and it consists of employees' basic information such as ID, name, and these checkboxes. However I need to create a system that manages whenever all the checkboxes have been checked.

I need it so once all checkboxes for an employee have been checked the information of this employee to be automatically deleted from the table. At the same time I need some contents automatically inserted to another table.

For example, there are two tables : `Development` and `CSA_Lisence`. `Development` is the table containing checkboxes and `CSA_Lisence` is the table that automatically updated when the checkboxes on `Development`  are fully checked. I don't know how to do this, how to code this on my VBA.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a function onto each `After Update` even on all of the checkboxes.  That event will call a function that you need to create which will check to see if all checkboxes have been check.

The function will look fairly close to what John had mentioned, however you will need to expand on it to check all ten boxes, if all are checked run an update query for your `CSA_Lisence` and then run a delete query for your `Development` table.  So something like this in to check the status of the training:

```vb
Public Function CheckCompletion() As Boolean

    Dim blnComplete As Boolean 
    Dim strCompletionSummary as String 

    strCompletionSummary = chk1 & chk2 & chk3 & chk4 & chk5 'etc

    If strCompletionSummary = "11111" Then 
        blnComplete = True
    Else 
        blnComplete = False
    End If 

End Function
```

Then on your `AfterUpdate` event you could call a function that handles if all of the boxes are checked, something like this:

```vb
Public Function UpdateEmployee() 

    If CheckCompletion Then 
        'Run Update Query
        'Run Delete Query
    End If 

End Function
```

Then you would have something like this in every checkbox's update event:

```vb
Private Sub chk1_AfterUpdate()
    Call UpdateEmployee()
End Sub
```

But you also need to know that at Stack Overflow isn't really a place where you can go to get people to write code for you so I have only provided you with a skeleton structure to start with.  So you will need to do some research for how to accomplish this and attempt it yourself.  But if you ever get stuck that is what we are here for :-)

Comment: Newd, John, thank you very much for your replies. I'm still a newbie, but your explanation really helpful in so many ways. I will be back if I get stuck. once again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm off base, but from your description it sounds like you should reconsider your table structure.  As of right now you are limiting yourself to these 10 check boxes per employee. What if the company changes their training, or adds more training.  Look into table Normalization.  Maybe add a table that consists of employeeID, TrainingID, and check box for complete or not. They can be populated when the user is created or new trainings are added or removed, but you'd be able to add as many records as needed if the training number or method changes.
I would also make the suggestion that it is best practice to not delete records such as these from your table. Instead use some type of identifier for Active or not. This also eliminates your need to insert a record into another table when you delete a record from this one. This type of procedure is usually unnecessary and complicates what should be changing a simple Boolean from true to false.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being you could make a string by concatenating the values of the checkboxes and check whether the value corresponds to your criteria (abs the value in order to get 1 instead of -1)
e.g.

```vb
checkCompletion = chk1 & chk2 & chk3 '(1 & 1 & 1 = "111")

If checkCompletion = "111" Then
    'Do Something
End If
```